Using Newtonsoft.Json for Deserializing an array of strings vs. an array of an array of strings in the same payload
I have found this answer to be quite helpful, but dbc specifically says,

The converter does not apply to lists whose items are also serialized as collections, e.g. List<string []>

The trouble is, I need to deserialize an array that might be an array of strings, or it might be an array of arrays of strings. So the example says it won't work in my case.
For example,
{"values": [ "foo", "bar" ]}

vs
{"values": [ [ "foo", "bar" ], [ "baz", "qux" ] ]}

I was thinking of implementing a custom class
    public class SingleOrArray<T> : ICollection<T>
    {
        public bool IsArray { get; set; } = false;
        public T Value { get; set; }

        public T[] Values { get { return _items.ToArray() } }

        private List<T> _items = new();

        // etc.
    }

With a deserialized object that looks like this:
    public class MyObject
    { [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArrayCollectionConverter<SingleOrArray<string[]>, string[]>))]
        public List<SingleOrArray<string[]>> Value { get; set; }
    }

But I don't know how to implement the JsonConverter that would handle this.
Here are my unit tests, which are passing, but I need it to handle string[] for this case:
    [Fact]
    public void SingleItemTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testData = "{ \"value\": \"a\" }";
        
        // Act
        var target = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(testData);

        // Assert
        Assert.False(target!.Value.IsArray);
        Assert.Equal("a", target!.Value.Value);
    }
    
    [Fact]
    public void ArrayItemTest1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var testData = "{ \"value\": [\"a\"] }";
        
        // Act
        var target = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(testData);

        // Assert
        Assert.True(target!.Value.IsArray);
        Assert.Equal("a", target!.Value.Values[0]);
    }

Notes:

[ "foo","bar" ] should become
SingleOrArray<string[]> { IsArray = false, Value = string["foo", "bar"] }

i.e. [["foo","bar"]] not [["foo"],["bar"]].

Mixed cases like ["foo",["bar"]] can be skipped.



Does it have to be a string array?  Would List<List<string>> work?

Also, what do you want [ "foo", "bar" ] to be deserialized to?  Do you want to be deserialize to [["foo","bar"]] or [["foo"],["bar"]]?

And finally for something pathological like ["foo",["bar"]], what do you want to do?

List<List<string>> would work too.

["foo",["bar"]] I think can be skipped.

OK, but should [ "foo", "bar" ] become [["foo","bar"]] or [["foo"],["bar"]]?

I would like [ "foo", "bar" ] to become SingleOrArray<string[]> { IsArray = false, Value = string["foo", "bar"] } but I'm not sure that's possible.

Rather that creating some custom collection type SingleOrArray<T>, I think it will be easier to define your Values property as a List<List<string>>:
public class Root
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArray2DListConverter<string>))]
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new();
}   

Assuming you do that, you need to decide how to deserialize a one-dimensional array like ["foo","bar"].  You have two choices:
Firstly, you could deserialize each inner item to its own array: [["foo"], ["bar"]].
With this design, you can use SingleOrArrayCollectionConverter<List<string>, string> from this answer to How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net by applying the converter to each item in the outer list.  You can do this by setting JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType to your desired converter type:
public partial class Root
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(SingleOrArrayCollectionConverter<List<string>, string>))]
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new();
}

Note that, with this design, JSON arrays with inconsistent nesting such as ["foo",["bar"]] are handled automatically and become [["foo"],["bar"]]
Demo fiddle #1 here.
Secondly, you could deserialize all the inner items to a single inner array: [["foo","bar"]].
With this design the converter from the linked question cannot be used and you must write your own from scratch:
public class SingleOrArray2DListConverter<TItem> : JsonConverter<List<List<TItem>>>
{
    public SingleOrArray2DListConverter() : this(false) { }
    public SingleOrArray2DListConverter(bool canWrite) { this.CanWrite = canWrite; }

    static void ValidateItemContract(IContractResolver resolver)
    {
        var itemContract = resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(TItem));
        if (itemContract is JsonArrayContract)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Item contract type {0} not supported.", itemContract));
    }

    public override List<List<TItem>>? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, List<List<TItem>>? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ValidateItemContract(serializer.ContractResolver);
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return default;
        var outerList = existingValue ?? (List<List<TItem>>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator!();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            int startDepth = reader.Depth;
            switch (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                // Empty 2d array
                break;
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                {// Nonempty 2d array
                    do
                    {
                        // TODO: decide whether to allow null inner lists.  If you want to allow them, remove the new() 
                        // And change the converter type to `List<List<TItem>?>`
                        outerList.Add(serializer.Deserialize<List<TItem>>(reader) ?? new()); 
                    }
                    while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray);
                }
                break;
                default:
                {// Nonempty 1d array
                    var list = new List<TItem>();
                    do
                    {
                        list.Add(serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader)!);
                    }
                    while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray);
                    outerList.Add(list);
                }
                break;
            }
            // Assert we are positioned at the end of the outer array with the same depth.
            Debug.Assert(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray && reader.Depth == startDepth);
        }
        else
        {
            // A single non-array item.
            outerList.Add(new() { serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader)! });
        }
        return outerList;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get; }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, List<List<TItem>>? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else if (value.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in value)
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}

// Base utilities

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

Then apply it as follows:
public class Root
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArray2DListConverter<string>))]
    public List<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new();
}   

Note that, with this design, JSON arrays with inconsistent nesting such as ["foo",["bar"]] cannot be handled and will result in an exception being thrown when encountered.
Demo fiddle #2 here.
If you really need to track whether the JSON had a 1d or 2d array, rather than creating your own SingleOrArray<T> collection, I would suggest inheriting from System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>.  Unlike List<T> this collection type is designed to be customized by providing protected methods like InsertItem() that can be overridden by derived types.
Thus you would need to modify your data model as follows:
public class Root
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrArray2DCollectionConverter<string>))]
    public SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<string>> Values { get; set; } = new();
}   

public class SingleOrMultipleCollection<T> : Collection<T>
{
    bool single;
    public bool Single
    {
        get => single;
        set
        {
            // TODO: decide what to do here if Count > 1.
            // You could truncate the collection or throw an exception.
            if (value && Count > 1)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();
            single = value;
            
        }
    }
    protected override void InsertItem(int index, T item)
    {
        // TODO: decide what to do if adding a 2nd item to a Single collection.  
        // You could set Single to false, or throw an exception.
        if (Single && Count >= 1)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot add a second item to a SingleOrMultipleCollection when Single == true");
        base.InsertItem(index, item);
    }
}

And tweak the 2d collection converter as follows:
public class SingleOrArray2DCollectionConverter<TItem> : JsonConverter<SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<TItem>>>
{
    static void ValidateItemContract(IContractResolver resolver)
    {
        var itemContract = resolver.ResolveContract(typeof(TItem));
        if (itemContract is JsonArrayContract)
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Item contract type {0} not supported.", itemContract));
    }

    public override SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<TItem>>? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<TItem>>? existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ValidateItemContract(serializer.ContractResolver);
        if (reader.MoveToContentAndAssert().TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return default;
        var outerList = existingValue ?? (SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<TItem>>)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator!();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            int startDepth = reader.Depth;
            switch (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.EndArray:
                // Empty 2d array
                break;
                case JsonToken.StartArray:
                {// Nonempty 2d array
                    outerList.Single = false;
                    do
                    {
                        // TODO: decide whether to allow null inner lists.  
                        // If you want to allow them, remove the new() and change the converter type to `List<List<TItem>?>`
                        outerList.Add(serializer.Deserialize<List<TItem>>(reader) ?? new()); 
                    }
                    while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray);
                }
                break;
                default:
                {// Nonempty 1d array
                    outerList.Clear();
                    outerList.Single = true;
                    var list = new List<TItem>();
                    do
                    {
                        list.Add(serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader)!);
                    }
                    while (reader.ReadToContentAndAssert().TokenType != JsonToken.EndArray);
                    outerList.Add(list);
                }
                break;
            }
            // Assert we are positioned at the end of the outer array with the same depth.
            Debug.Assert(reader.TokenType == JsonToken.EndArray && reader.Depth == startDepth);
        }
        else
        {
            // A single non-array item.
            // TODO: decide how to set Single here.
            outerList.Add(new() { serializer.Deserialize<TItem>(reader)! });
        }
        return outerList;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, SingleOrMultipleCollection<List<TItem>>? value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value == null)
            writer.WriteNull();
        else if (value.Single && value.Count == 1)
        {
            foreach (var item in value)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in value)
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }
    }
}

// Base utilities

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader ReadToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader) =>
        reader.ReadAndAssert().MoveToContentAndAssert();

    public static JsonReader MoveToContentAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None)       // Skip past beginning of stream.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment) // Skip past comments.
            reader.ReadAndAssert();
        return reader;
    }

    public static JsonReader ReadAndAssert(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(reader);
        if (!reader.Read())
            throw new JsonReaderException("Unexpected end of JSON stream.");
        return reader;
    }
}

Note that JSON arrays with inconsistent nesting also cannot be handled with this design.
Demo fiddle #3 here.

@devlord - You commented previously that List<List<string>> would work too, but if you need to track what kind of JSON was encountered I added a third option using a custom collection type.
